# Can custom UIElement implement IList<UIElement> and be assigned children directly (in XAML)?

Tags: wpf, xaml, collections, panel, children

Scenario: I have a range of custom `UIElements` (in fact, I have replaced all the standard WPF `FrameworkElements` I would use with lighter, more efficient counterparts) for a custom layout system intended to only use those. They all inherit from a class called `Surface` (which in turn is a direct descendant of `UIElement`).

I am now wondering if my version of `Panel` (let's call it `SurfacePanel`) can simply implement `IList<Surface>` and allow child `Surface` elements to be added directly to it, rather than to a `Children` property (as with regular WPF panels), **in XAML**.

To illustrate - in codebehind, I can do now this:

```
SurfacePanel.Add(child);
```

And from that, I would like to be able to do this in XAML:

```
<SurfacePanel>
    <child />
</SurfacePanel>
```

But XAML seems to require me to have a codebehind pattern like this:

```
SurfacePanel.Children.Add(child)
```

(I don't really need these controls to support XAML to work in the runtime environment, but when testing and prototyping, I like to make my UI controls "XAML friendly" so I can benefit from the visual designer in VS (along with the property pane etc), if nothing more than as a 'preview' window).

Since my controls inherit from `UIElement` (and have the proper Measure/Arrange/Render overrides and so on), they function quite well when put on, say, a regular `Canvas`or `Grid`. But the VS XAML parser is not too happy about my `SurfacePanel` (that implements `IList<Surface>`) *when I am adding children to it in markup*. It says "Cannot add content to an object of type "SurfacePanel"".

I know that if I add a `Children` property of an appropriate type and add an attribute to the `SurfaceCanvas` class (`[ContentProperty("Children")]`), it will work. But since the `SurfacePanel` is itself a collection capable of the same thing, is there a way to make XAML 'get it'?

---

Edit:

I can solve the XAML 'compliance' by adding a `Children` property on the `SurfacePanel` that simply returns its inner `List`, but then adding and removal of elements on that directly bypasses the internal logic that wire the child elements up.

If the inner list was an `ObservableCollection`, I could do it the conventional way and do the wiring in a `CollectionChanged` event handler - but basically the whole point of integrating `IList` in the Panel directly is to avoid that..

---

Edit 2:

This "works" (but bypasses the wiring):

```
[ContentProperty("Children")]
public class SurfacePanel : Surface, IList<Surface>
{
    private readonly List<Surface> _children = new List<Surface>(); 

    public List<Surface> Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
    }
}
```

I cannot return `this` because `SurfacePanel` is not a `List<Surface>`, but an `IList<Surface>`.

If I change the property to

```
    public IList<Surface> Children
    {
        get { return this; }
    }
```

I get an error message even with the following XAML (but not with `<m:SurfacePanel/>`):

```
<m:SurfacePanel>
</m:SurfacePanel>
```

The error message is

`Cannot set content property 'Children' on element 'SurfacePanel'. 'Children' has incorrect access level or its assembly does not allow access.`

Comment: This is very strange and absolutely unnecessary. Your CustomPanel is not itself a List, it is a Parent Element for other `UIElements` hence the `Children` Collection.

Comment: Your comment is very strange and absolutely unnecessary. My custom panel is a container that has children (and nothing else), therefore Panel.Add(child) is a very logical pattern to incorporate (and much more concise than having to go through an additional level, i.e. via a redundant property). You could say that the Panel is the graphical representation of a List. In any case, the question is not whether other people are able to wrap their heads around the approach, but whether it is possible to do in XAML.

Comment: Your comment is so strange, in fact, that I wonder what you think about XAML's own syntax for adding children [directly!] to a panel..

Comment: Return `this` for the `Children` property instead of the internal list?

Comment: I thought of that, too, but I get a compiler error (from the XAML): `Cannot set content property 'Children' on element 'SurfacePanel'. 'Children' has incorrect access level or its assembly does not allow access`. Although that is perhaps a semi-unrelated issue that can be resolved by fixing something elsewhere..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also implement `IList` and declare the `Children` property like this:

```
[ContentProperty("Children")]
public class SurfacePanel : Surface, IList, IList<Surface>
{
    public IList Children
    {
        get { return this; }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: That works. Unfortunately, it makes my class _ass ugly_ by having to implement all the `IList` members in addition to the `IList<T>` ones.. Which means I can either choose to have two sets of every member in my class, or just go with the sloppy `IList` ones (that operate on `object` - blah). Neither appeals to me, as I am a bit anal about these things - I hate hacks / inelegant solutions just to make things "work". And all this just to make XAML grasp a pattern that itself is using (i.e. adding children directly to panels).. If only I could make it understand that SurfacePanel is a list..!

Comment: I guess a really elegant solution would be to follow the WPF design pattern and not directly implement `IList<Surface>`, but instead *only* have a Children property. You'll have that public Children property in any case, and would have less code without the list methods. Put your special collection stuff in an internal SurfaceCollection implementation (similar to UIElementCollection).

Comment: The WPF FrameworkElements are bloated and inefficient because they are so general purpose. The very point of what I am doing is to sidestep them and the whole XAML paradigm. My framework works very well - it's only when i need to cross paths with WPF and XAML these things come up. My solution is not intended for / doesn't need XAML, and I design components to be elegant in _that_ context, not for XAML.. It's only because the VS visual designer / XAML editor is helpful as a preview tool while I am developing that I even need to comply.. I hate having to deal with it. But thanks for you help!

Comment: That said, I might _temporarily_ swap the innards of the `SurfacePanel` class to host a `SurfaceCollection` à la UIElementCollection, as you say (that's how I did it in the previous version), and then just switch back once I am ready to shed the whole XAML burden. Apart from the `Children` property, the class should look the same from the outside.

Comment: Even though it's not really the solution I was looking / hoping for, I'm going to accept your answer since it's one (the only?) way of getting around the problem  (+ you've been very helpful with some related issues and I couldn't be happier about giving you the credits). What I ended up doing was inheriting my real, clean `SurfacePanel` into a `XamlSurfacePanel` class that does implement `IList` as you suggested. It works in XAML for prototyping and testing purposes and can easily be removed from the solution later on.